# MusicLibrary in Network Location throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, uwp

I've got my UWP app accessing the MusicLibrary KnownFolder which is located on a network drive (either `\\` or mapped).

If I edit files in the Music Library directly from windows I have no problems, however when my app tries to edit the file (tags in this case) it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. If I swap the MusicLibrary to a local folder everything is both hunky and dory.

I have Music Library and Private Networks Capabilities selected.

Has anyone run into something like this before?

Update 1:
Not Relevant

Update 2 (update):

See below for an example that somewhat succinctly replicates this issue for me. I've stuck it in a button for convenience. Apparently this was related to the MediaPlayer, I didn't realise at the time.

When MediaLibrary is set to a local directory, say C:\Music, it works fine. When set to a remote location, say X:\HomeServerShares\Music it will throw an exception.

Git: https://github.com/Rekrii/UWPMusicLibAccessDeniedExample

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get a list of files from the music library
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
            //Select random file from the music library
            //using GetFileFromPathAsync as per comment below
            StorageFile infoFile = 
                 await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(
                     files[new Random().Next(0, files.Count - 1)].Path);

            //Create a MediaSource and add it to a MediaPlaybackList
            MediaSource source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(infoFile);
            MediaPlaybackList list = new MediaPlaybackList();
            list.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));

            //Create a MediaPlayer and add the MediaPlaybackList to it
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.Source = list;
            //'mediaPlayer' was created in xaml: <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"/>
            mediaPlayer.SetMediaPlayer(player);

            //Get the music properties of the audio file
            MusicProperties musicProperties = await infoFile.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            //Edit them (so UWP will attempt to edit the file)
            musicProperties.Title = "woo";
            //Save the properties...
            //When using C:\etc as a MusicLibrary, this will work fine
            //When using a mapped location say X:\etc this save will thorw access denied
            await musicProperties.SavePropertiesAsync();
        }
```

I have confirmed that the user accessing the network drive has FullControl permissions, is the folder Owner, and can edit the files from Explorer.

I can also rename the file with C# to demonstrate correct access as renaming should be approximately similar to editing. The 'path' I am using is in the form of X:\etc where X:\ is the mapped letter.

May the error come down to the `SavePropertiesAsync` call?

Comment: Did you set capabilities in Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: @Isma Yep. Both in VS and checked the file too (to be sure).

Comment: How do you access the MusicLibrary in Network Location? Could you share a [MCVE] that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT Thanks for the prompt I've updated the question with an MCV example with more details.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Universal Naming Convention (UNC) is the naming system commonly used in Microsoft Windows for accessing shared network folders. For more info, please refer [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

This is my Package.appxmanifest:

```
  <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="UWP_how_to_show_image_from_a_network.App">
    <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="UWP how to show image from a network" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="UWP how to show image from a network" BackgroundColor="transparent">
      <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
      </uap:DefaultTile>
      <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    </uap:VisualElements>
    <Extensions>
      <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
        <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="mymusictest">
          <uap:DisplayName>MyMusicTest</uap:DisplayName>
          <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:FileType>.mp3</uap:FileType>
          </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
      </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>
  </Application>
</Applications>
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
  <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
</Capabilities>
```

It will not throw the `UnauthorizedAccessException` and we can get the folder by [`StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder#Methods_) method.

Comment: I've used the same capabilities above as well as the mp3 file type dec. Ive updated the GitHub files to use GetFileFrompathAsync. The user accessing the network is both the file owners and has FullControl permissions and I am able to edit the files from Explorer.

Comment: I can also rename the file with C# to demonstrate correct access as renaming should be approximately similar to editing. The 'path' I am using is in the form of X:\etc where X:\ is the mapped letter.